# Cannot type in input text field

Tags: html, css, input

I am not able to type in the input field. When I remove the first div that has the id="viewport" I am able to type in the input field. How am I able to solve this?

```html
<div id="viewport"></div>
<div class="form">
  <h2 id="h2">Need a project from<br>Google Cloud Storage?</h2>
  <form id="fileDownloadForm" method="GET" action="downloadBlob2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="textBox" name="objectToSearch" placeholder="Type the name of the project here." />
    <button id="downloadBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn_primary">Download</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: not reproducable. you can test this code by itself and see that it's working. Perhaps you have other contributing factors.

Comment: Post CSS specifically what is #viewport

Comment: Without the CSS, seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/eLtc4mgq/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was posting my code in jsfiddle but then received the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may solve this by adding css attribute `#textBox{ z-index:1000; }`. It seems that viewport block is too big and overflowing the input field. z-index makes the input field more "important" - the bigger it is, the more important the element becomes.

Comment: Haha! I tried this already but with z-index: 1. 1000 works! Thank you.

Do you know if a higher number for z-index or multiple z indexes demand a longer loading time for the web page in any way?

Comment: Glad I could help! :) No, I don't think so. Since it's just an attribute to a css file, it simply adds a little more information to a css file. I use it in my work very often to be honest, still haven't noticed any problems with loading. Everything loads pretty smoothly

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Then I found that I used preventDefault() on keydown event.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {e.preventDefault()}
```

Answer (score 1):

just in case to others, what works for me is putting   in the immediate  tag. So in this case I will try to put it in:

```
<div class="form" style="z-index: 1000 !important;">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, somehow the text color changed to `white`. I found it by accidentally double-clicking the input field after typing few characters.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i used Reactjs app for using

```
<input type="text" title="Search for products, brands and more" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for products, brands and more" name="" value="" />
```

You can see i put value="" so it is blank. That's why it was not working.